# How to derive asymptotics for this expression?

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

$S = \frac{3t^4+3t^3}{2} \cdot \frac{t^{3n}-(t+2)^{n}}{t^3-t-2}$

$ t>1, n>1$

Intuitively, it feels like this expression behaves "like" $t^{3n+1}$, but it seems that some constant is lacking, but I don't see how to formally come up with some asymptotics.

Comment: Take a factor $t^{3n+4}$ out of the numerator leaving the other factor as a constant plus negative powers of $t$ (which go to zero as $t$ increases in value). Do the same with the denominator (using a different power - but leaving a constant as the highest term of the rest). Incidentally, when you say "behaves like" it matters greatly which values of $t$ you care about. This technique works for large absolute values of $t$, but around zero the behaviour is quite different, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is good
$$S = \frac32(t^4+t^3) \times \frac{t^{3n}-(t+2)^{n}}{t^3-t-2}$$
$$S= \frac32 t^4 \left(1+\frac{1}{t}\right)\times t^{3n-3}\times\frac {t^3-\frac{(t+2)^n}{ t^{3n-3} } }{t^3-t-2}$$ So, when $t$ is large and $n>1$ the last term tends to $1$ and we are left with
$$S =\frac32 t^{3n+1} \left(1+\frac{1}{t}+O\left(\frac{1}{t^2} \right)\right)$$